# ZF2 hide navigation entry in menu

Tags: zend-framework2

i want to hide a navigation entry in a menu. In the breadcrums the entry should be visible. The helper provides a method "set/getRenderInvisible", but how can i mark the entry as invisble? That way i could render invisible entries in the breadcrumbs and hide them in the menu.

I use partial views on both navigations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using navigation configuration, as shown in [navigation quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.navigation.quick-start.html), just add `visible` key with boolean value:

```php
     'navigation' => [
         'default' => [
             [
                 'label' => 'Home',
                 'route' => 'home',
                 'visible' => false,
             ],
         ],
     ],
```

It is property of navigation page class ([source](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.4/library/Zend/Navigation/Page/AbstractPage.php#L137)). And you can check if page is visible with [isVisible](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.4/library/Zend/Navigation/Page/AbstractPage.php#L869) method on page object in your partial template.